# ggplot2 Facet wrapping a filtered variable while keeping background geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to create a set of small multiple line charts, where in each chart all lines are visible as light grey/background but in each individual chart one line is one highlighted.

As an example I want to go from this chart: [facet_wrap without previous geom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9ESC.png) to a facet_wrap that would have two plots, each with all grey dashed lines, and one coloured line per plot.

I can facet_wrap so each highlighted line has it's own chart (but no other background lines show)(facet_fail below) and I can create individual charts which have all lines in grey and a highlighted single line (ind_chart below), but I can't get both at the same time.

I'm sure I'm missing a simple setting here but can't see it sorry.

Here's a simplified example of the data and charts I've made so far.

(the lines have been converted to radar/polar coordinates but I don't think that should matter?)

```
library(tidyverse)

#variables
food <- rep(c("apple", "pear", "orange"),3)
sense <- as.factor(rep(c("taste", "texture", "appearance"),each = 3))
score <- sample(0:10, 9)

#dataframe
df <- data.frame(food,sense,score) %>% 
  mutate(theta = (as.integer(sense)-1)*(360/n_distinct(y)*pi/180)+pi/2) %>% #transrom data to         polar with cartesian coords
  mutate(x = cos(theta)*score,
         y = sin(theta)*score)%>% 
  rbind(filter(., sense == "taste")) #repeat first row so that geom_path completes circuit

# Plot

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = food))+
  geom_point(colour = "gray", size = 3)+
  geom_path(colour = "gray", size = 1, linetype = "longdash")+
  geom_spoke(data = data.frame( x = 0,
                                y = 0,
                                angle =seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, length.out = 4)+pi/2,
                                radius = 10),
             aes(x = x, y = y, angle = angle, radius = radius, group = NULL),
             colour = "darkgray", size = 0.8)+
    theme_void()
p

# individual chart is correct
ind_chart <- p + geom_path(data = filter(df, food == "apple" | food == "orange"), aes(color = food), size = 2)

# facet wrap by 'food' creates multiples without backgroud geom_path's from p

fltr <- filter(df, food == "apple" | food == "orange")

facet_fail <- p +
  geom_path(data = fltr , aes(color = food))+
  facet_wrap(~food)+
  coord_equal()
```

Comment: Your example fails on the `mutate(theta .... `, `y` not found.

Comment: But regardless, you can't use `food` as the variable name in both `df` and `fltr`, since then facetting will happen to the geoms defined using either data. Rename the variable in one of the data.frames and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman, I had a feeling it was something stupid like that... much appreciated!